# Sum with one to many Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, sum, spring-data-jpa, aggregation

I am trying to get a sum with a one to many relationship, illustrated by the following relationship (only parent shown):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7348332185233715983L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="CHILDREN", referencedColumnName="PARENT_ID")
    private List<Child> children;

    @Formula("(select sum(select height from children))")
    private BicDecimal totalHeight
}
```

It is pretty straight forward with no restrictions and even with static restrictions.  I am having trouble when the children list is restricted dynamically though.

In my case, I am using spring data and jpa.  I am using specifications to restrict the children and am getting the appropriate list of children, but obviously the sum is still for unrestricted children because there is no where clause in the @Formula tag.

I do not want to iterate over the list in java for performance reasons and because the results are paginated. Also, the sum is not of the paginated results, but of all results.

I am new to Spring Data/JPA.  Historically, I could build this query dynamically or use hibernate criteria.  I am OK running a completley separate query to make this calculation.  it is not required that I use the @Formula annotation as there is only 1 aggregation per call.  In a hibernate framework, I could just state the select clause as "sum(field)" and build the criteria.  In the Spring Data/JPA framework, I can build the specifications fine which covers the criteria, but I have no idea how to manipulate the select part of the query since it seems tied so tightly to the entity.

Using the @Query annotation on the repository works as its own query if I know which fields I need to restrict on, but often the fields are null and need to be ignored for the query.  There are 8 possible fields, leaving me with 256 possible combinations (2^8).  That is too many methods for this in the repository.

Any ideas outside of switching frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer to this old question since I had a somewhat similar problem recently.

I decided to go with a custom repository with a method that does the aggregation based on any Specification passed into it. Specifications can be combined to compose dynamic criteria (see org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications)

So my repository to above Child height problem would look like below:

```
package something

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

@Repository
public class ChildHeightRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;


    public Long getTotalHeight(Specification<Child> spec) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

        Root root = query.from(Child.class);

        return ((Long) entityManager.createQuery(
                query.where(spec.toPredicate(root, query, cb))
                        .select(cb.sum(root.get("height")))).getSingleResult());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in JPQL

```
select sum(d.height) from Parent a join a.children d
```

If you dont want to ignore nulls

```
select sum(d.height) from Parent a left join a.children d
```

I think other question you have is how to filter depending on the properties . I mean if you need to have a where statement with several combinations.

Why you don't try to use a List and adding to the list all the predicates you want to apply depending on the combinations you want to have. Example

Create query

```
   CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Double.class);
    Root<Parent> root = cq.from(Parent.class)
    Join<Parent, Child> join = cq.join(("children")); 
    cq.select(cb.<Double>sum(join.get("height")));
```

Create the list of predicates

```
List<Predicates> listOfpredicates = new ArrayList<Predicates>();
if(property1 != null && !"".equals(property1){
      PatameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class, "valueOfproperty1")
      listOfpredicates.add(cb.equal(join.get("property1"),p);
}
```

Then add to the CriteriaQuery

```
if(listOfPredicates.size() == 1)
   cq.where(listOfPredicates.get(0))
else
   cq.where(cb.and(listOfPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
```

Finally execute the query.

```
TypedQuery<Double> q = em.createQuery(cq);
q.getResultList();
```

This will create dynamically your query with any combination.

Answer (score 0):

6 years late but it still took me a while to get it to work, here is how I would do it for your mapping:

```
@Formula("(select sum(children.height) from children_table children inner join Parent p on children.parent_id=p.id where children.parent_id=parent_id)")
private BicDecimal totalHeight
```

Stuff you need to take care of:

1. add `()` to the beginning and end of your formula otherwise the syntax of the sql wont be translated correctly.
2. the formula query is a native SQL query to my understanding and not a JPQL some one might want to correct me on this?.
3. properties are those of the tables and not what you name your properties in Java so the column names and table names have to actually be the table names.